What is the best way to sync database based on data from an external API? Cronjob performance issue
I have a cronjob which runs every 2 hours to get data from external API to keep data up-to-date. The cronjob will first get the whole list of data from external API and list of id from our own database. If the id existed in our database, it will compare the content and update accordingly if content difference. If the id does not exist, then add the data into our database. However, there will be performance issue as data increases because might need to loop the whole list of data and compare. Is there any suggestion that can handle the performance issue for this cronjob?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The only thing that has no influence at all on this is cron, but that's the only tag you applied. Please, take the [tour] and read [ask].
